# Как получить уникальное Id для девайса?

Tags: java, android

Как получить никальное id для `device`-a которое не будет изменяться даже после перепрошивки ?в котором я могу быть уверен на все 100 %.это `MacAdress`,`Imei` или что? Или чтото другое

Comment: И мак-адрес, и имеи можно изменить даже без перепрошивки.

Comment: @Эникейщик  для этого и задан вопрос )

Comment: @Эникейщик изменил для таких придирчивых как ты

Comment: Думаю, что придется усердно поработать с ответами [на этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id), потому что простого решения, похоже, не существует.

Comment: Может Вы не так к задаче подходите - зачем идентифицировать именно аппарат?

Comment: @woesss бэкэнд хочет )

Comment: Все идентификаторы, которые может предоставить система можно изменить - китайцы вообще их сбрасывают вместе со сбросом настроек. На PC применяют подсчёт хеша оборудования, но на мобилках про такое не слышал и для этого нужен доступ к драйверам.

Comment: Вообще, имхо, для любых разумных целей устройство с изменившимся IMEI можно считать другим устройством. Другое дело, что не у любого устройства вообще есть IMEI.